# How to detect and configure Gimbal beacon in android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging, beacon, gimbal

I want to implement Gimbal beacon in android app, I created account on Gimbal site. I got API key too.
I want to know, What is Factory id for Gimbal beacon? How to get it? and  bit confused how to detect and configure it in android application.

Answer (score 0):

Factory id is written inside of Beacon. You can open beacon with a sharp object. when you open it, you will see a battery. Just above it, there is 9 digit alpha numeric string.